# Briskers and tzitzis on shabbas

Tags: tzitzis, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

It is well known that the briskers are worried to wear tzitzis on shabbas where there is no eruv because of the opinion of Rebbi (Baal Hamaor). Did Rav Yosha Ber Soloveitchik follow this opinion, or he wore tzitzis on shabbas?

Comment: I would imagine an eruv wouldn’t change much either. Briskers tend not to rely on city-wide eruvin...

Comment: Very vaild point

Comment: Why the downvote,please explain

Comment: @sam While I didn't downvote, I would imagine that it seems from your question that you did not put in much effort.  As an example, you mentioned something "well-known" without providing any source, for it (nor did you explain it in detail).  While in general I appreciate historical questions, I can see how some might feel like this is not really important or useful information.  Additionally, it was written in a way that seemed a bit rushed (perhaps from a phone?), spelling and grammar-wise.

Comment: @DanF your edit has now caused the spelling of ציצית to be in three different ways: "tziztis", "tziztzis" and "tzizts".  If you want to edit it for spellings of Hebrew words, try to keep it uniform, please.

Comment: @רבות מחשבות , maskim,was in a rush,didnt want to forget to ask it,also it seems ppl are interested enough because they like the answer,even though its connected to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first piece in Rav Herschel Schachter book on the minhagim of Rabbi Soloveitchik entitled פניני הרב, Rav Schachter writes that Rabbi Soloveitchik did wear tzitzis on shabbos[image]

Comment: @sam Hope that helps